# PHP - Parse HTML, Select tag, Insert another HTML string inside selected tag

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am trying to insert HTML string inside another HTML element parsed in created DOM with loaded HTML from string;

**Here is my code:**

PHP:

```
$str = $attributes["description_text"]; // HTML string
$dom = new DOMDocument; // initialize the domdocument
$dom->loadHTML($str); // load our html into the $dom object
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('mark'); // retrieving elements by tag

$gear = $dom->createElement('a', "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
$dom->appendChild($gear);
    
$output_dom = $dom->saveHTML();

return '<p>'. $output_dom .'</p>';
```

HTML ($str content):

```
Phasellus eu arcu vestibulum, ultrices massa eu, <mark>TOOLTIP</mark> sodales dui.
```

Desired Result (`a` tag inside `mark` tag):

```
<p>Phasellus eu arcu vestibulum, ultrices massa eu, <mark>TOOLTIP<a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></mark> sodales dui.</p>
```

Current Output:

```
<p>Phasellus eu arcu vestibulum, ultrices massa eu, <mark>TOOLTIP</mark> sodales dui.</p> 
<a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
```

So now new string appended in the end of whole paragraph, not inside `mark` tag

Comment: You find the elements to be manipulated in `$items`, so you need to call `appendChild()` on those elements and not the whole document (`$dom`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, selected an `item(0)` from elements stored in `$items`, and called `appendChild()` on it, thanks to [@NigelRen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren)

```
$first_mark = $items->item(0);
$first_mark->appendChild($gear);
```